# MS Access rookie - Ask for confirmation before updating a record

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I'm trying to create a small MS Access database to ease up my everyday job. The problem is I'm a noob when it comes to databases. **I'm trying to prevent the user from accidentaly updating the wrong record.**

- I have a table of records, some of which are not 100% complete.
- I created a query that lists only these incomplete records.
- On a form, the mentioned query is fed into a listbox.
- I want the user to be able to pick an incomplete record from this listbox and fill in some of the remaining parts of the record in a bunch of text boxes. What I don't like is that **the record gets updated** as you fill in the form fields (they're bound to the table) **WITHOUT any request for confirmation**. If the user picks a wrong record at the start, the records are gonna get messy with every text box filled. Or that's what seems to be happening.

Here's my idea of the user form:

[image: my idea of the user form]

Is there a correct way to do this? **I could force it all with VBA** but I'd rather avoid that and use a more native (correct) solution.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using VBA. In this instance, I'd use unbound controls on the form, and use a submit button to use either a recordset or update SQL statement to amend the data, with a clear button to clear the text boxes.

Comment: Will definitely need some code. Possibly form BeforeUpdate procedure which has a Cancel argument.

Comment: Access has no way to do this besides using VBA. Either of the 2 suggestions above will work. For the most control, go with unbound controls. But for something quick, the BeforeUpdate event will do a good job.

Comment: VBA is the "native (correct) solution" for **everything** in Access.

Answer (score 1):

[Table constraints](https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/constraints.html) are an important part of database design. Any grouping of elements that together are required should be in their own table. This way the [required fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/require-a-value-in-a-field-d6bf6ff6-d653-48ef-b484-54a33c36f6c6) must be entered for every record in that table.

For each data entry step you will have one or more tables representing the required data of that step.

If you are following [database normalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description) best practices this should be simple to achieve because your data will already be broken down in to small elements that can have required fields to complete each record.

If you have a record that contains fields that are filled out at different steps then that is a design smell that indicates your table is not properly normalized.

In MS-Access, the forms will follow these rules set in the tables. You will not be able to save a record that has required fields missing.